# Proof of Sperner's Lemma

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry

I am looking for a concise and mathematically robust proof of the [Sperner's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma).

The easiest proof I found so far is [Math Pages Blog](http://mathpages.blogspot.co.il/2010/05/sperners-lemma.html), but I don't get it without few details.

Following is the proof of the Sperner's lemma from the Math Pages Blog.

**Sperner's Lemma Proof:**

> To prove the lemma for the $n$-th dimension all we need to do is:
>   Let $v$ be an inner vertice in $T$. Define a linear function of $t$ that moves this vertice to the outer vertice of the same color when $t$ goes from 0 to 1.

Q:What does it mean the outer vertices, it's a vertex on of the facets of the initial simplex? What does it mean $t$ goes from 0 to 1, according to the definition it just moves any inner vertex to outer vertex.

> The volume of any given simplex in $T$ is the determinant of the vectors that correspond to the vertices of the simplex.

Q:example, dimension $2$, as a result of triangulation there are triangles, vectors that correspond to vertices are 2 dimensional vectors and there three of them, how to compute the determinant in this case.

> Since all the vectors are linear functions of $t$, the volume is a polynomial of degree $n$. The sum of the volumes is thus also a polynomial of degree $n$. For $t=0$ the polynomial is obviously the volume of the outer simplex (for n=2 it is the volume of ABC). However if t is only slightly bigger then zero, we still have a triangulation so the sum of the volumes is the same and therefore the polynomial is a constant. For simplicity lets say that the volume is exactly 1. Now, when t=1 the volume of all the simplexes that are not colored in n colors becomes zero. On the other hand, the volumes of the other simplexes are either 1 or (-1) (depends on orientation). And with this we are done - if the sum of the volumes is 1 there are must be simplexes that have volume 1 but this is only possible if there is an odd number of simplexes with n colors.

The rest question is due to I don't understand the nature of the function $t$ from the begging.

I tried to find this proof in more formal format, but so far with no success.

I will appreciate if someone could shed the light on this proof of the sperner's lemma. In addition, if you familiar with more intuitive proof, please share it with us.

Comment: The proof presented in the Wiki page you refer to is the proof I'm familiar with, which is extremely straightforward and intuitive.

Comment: Engelking (general topology) has a complete proof.

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice and intuitive proof by induction. http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture03.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The proof on that site appears in

Using Volume to Prove Sperner's Lemma
Andrew McLennan and Rabee Tourky
Economic Theory
[Vol. 35, No. 3 (Jun., 2008), pp. 593-597](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40282878?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

You may wish to read that paper.

(The main ingredient of the proof is due to the genius of John Milnor who established Brower's fixed point theorem through a polynomial homotopy of the change of variable theorem)